# Issue with Postgres views and EntityFramework6.Npgsql

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

Issue with `EntityFramework6.Npgsql` for .NET 4.8 framework.

I am trying to import views from postgres env, we are getting error of primary key not found in views, however primary keys are added in tables.

For the work around I added views manually in .NET `.edmx` file.

- In the context file, I added reference
- Added Entity file in `*.tt`
- Added reference of views in `.edmx` at different places like store, mapping and entitySet.

It is compiling and not showing any error. However when I am running the solution it is throwing this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=The entity type vwuserlogin is not part of the model for the current context.
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet1.Initialize() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet1.get_InternalContext()
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_Local()
>
> 'connectData.vwuserlogins.Local' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

- Npgsql version: -4.1.12
- EntityFramework.Npgsql- 6.4.3
- PostgreSQL version: 14
- Operating System: Windows

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.